# The getter '(' isn't defined for the type

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this code block that I want to use to retrieve data from firebase database. But I have issue with the code as it brings error message as below. Please I need help to resolve the issue.
The error message

> The getter '(' isn't defined for the type 'UsersData'.
> Try importing the library that defines '(', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a get

The code

```
void _getPhoneNos(BuildContext context) async {
fb.Database db = fb.database();
fb.DatabaseReference<ReferenceJsImpl> dataRef = db.ref('users');
dataRef.onValue.listen((event) {
  fb.DataSnapshot snapshot = event.snapshot;

  if (snapshot == null) {
    print("Result is Empty");
    return;
  }
   List<UsersData>usersInfo= snapshot.val();

     usersInfo.forEach((Item) {
    _singleTextFieldcontroller.text = Item.Item("phone");
  });
});
```

This is the UsersData.

```
  class UsersData {
  String id;
  String name;
  String type;
  String phone;
  String residential;

  UsersData({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.type,
    this.phone,
    this.residential,
  });

  UsersData.fromJson(this.id, Map data) {
    name = data['name'];
    type = data['type'];
    phone = data['phone'];
    residential = data['residential'];
  }

  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An 's' is missing :

```
UserData({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.type,
    this.phone,
    this.residential,
  });
```

Should be

```
UsersData({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.type,
    this.phone,
    this.residential,
  });
```

Comment: I edited and added the ''s'' but it still give error message.

Comment: I proposed another answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in this line :

```
_singleTextFieldcontroller.text = Item.Item("phone");
```

Item is an instance of UsersData. If you want to access their phone variable you should do :

```
_singleTextFieldcontroller.text = Item.phone;
```